# Mathematica, why am i geting imaginary numbers?

Tags: physics, trigonometry

Just started using Mathematica and would appreciate any help resolving this issue - which I believe is in the sys of eq (second line below)

```
a=1.65;vAo=4;vBo=0;vCo=0;vC = vCx;vA=-1.92;vB=vBx+vBy;

Solve[{vAo==vBx+vC,0==vA+vBy,vAo^2==vA^2+vB^2+vC^2,0.75 vAo==(1.8-a) vA+c vC},{vBx,vBy,vC,c}]
```

[image]

Comment: Because of `vAo^2 == vA^2 + vB^2 + vC^2` this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract only real solutions from the result of Solve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56555/how-to-extract-only-real-solutions-from-the-result-of-solve)

Comment: your problem is in the formulation, which is out of scope of this site. Two things I see, `Va` should be positive consistent with the direction of the arrow, but you need to follow that convention through all the equations. Also the energy of `B` is not `(vBx+vBy)^2` it is `vBx^2+vBy^2`.

Comment: That FIXED it!  Thanks George!